# Using getExtra() - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a Fragment with the `onItemClick`-method in which I call another Activity and pass `id` parameter:

```
public class MoviesListFragment extends Fragment {
  // some code
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView mid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textID);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), InfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", mid.getText());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

So, in another activity (InfoActivity.java) I'm trying to get `id`-value:

```
public class InfoActivity extends Activity {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    private final String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    // some code
```

and get an exception on this line: `intent.getStringExtra("id");`

Where I made a mistake?

Comment: whats the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
private final String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Should be called from inside the onCreate() or similar method, otherwise it is called when the `Activity` object is created, before the intent is passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private final String id;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
         id = intent.getStringExtra("id");

    }
```